# openfire user statuses always offline

Tags: xmpp, openfire

Is there anything in particular I need to configure to get the users statuses working? All the users seem to be offline no matter what.

Chat seems to work fine, but obv it's not ideal not knowing who is online at any one time.

w://

Comment: Can you exchange IMs with those who appear to be offline?

Comment: yeah - it all works ok - they're just reported to be offline

Answer (score 2):

Did you figure this out? I notice in my new install of openfire (windows service, using the build in hsqldb.) That when I log into the admin panel is shows what users are online, but spark shows users as offline. We can still chat with each other, but have no indication of who is online.

A work around is to have the users log off and log back in and re-add people as contacts. This solves the problem for a couple of days. (thus far in limited testing)

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your users send `presence` stanzas. If so then openfire make them online automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem until I realized that I didn't have the group settings configured correctly. To have the contact list show up in some clients and to show online status, you have to enable contact list sharing and specify the contact list name. If you don't specify the list name it won't work:

You can see the below screenshot:

[image]

This is in the Users/Groups tab > Groups > Edit Group